# addsubview gives wrong output?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, addsubview

i am using following code , but subview is added below the the parentview not ON  parent view(self.view)..any help please?

```
 -(IBAction)okbutton:(id)sender

 {

        obj = [[imgViewNextController alloc] initWithNibName:@"green" bundle:nil];

             obj.view.frame = self.view.frame;

   [UIView beginAnimations:@"curldown" context:nil];
     [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
   [UIView setAnimationDuration:.5];
   [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.view cache:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:obj.view];
   //[self.view insertSubview:obj.view aboveSubview:self.view];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a TableView ?

Some objects do (strange) things, so it may be related.

If possible give use more information about your self object.

By the way, you can try

```
[ self.view insertSubview: atIndex: ];
```

or

```
[ self.view insertSubview: aboveSubview: ];>
```

Good Luck !